# How send mail(newsletter) using simplenews drupal site

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I am new with drupal and using simplenews module for newsletters

How we send newletter using simplenews

I tried a lot of R&D but not able to send newsletter, everytime it shows sent 0/0

Can any body please guide me regards this

I am showing some images here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax2sD.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV1D0.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blczf.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuvd6.png

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 1):

Well, the image shows that you are not using cron. Nevertheless, is cron set up for your site? If not, try installing the poormanscron module and see what happens.

Comment: Yes I am not using cron..but its set up.. can you help me to use it.. I am not understanding Why is show Sent 0/0 as in image http://i.imgur.com/Blczf.png

Comment: Is Drupal able to send any other mails? Like when registering? Are you getting the message if you're just sending to the test address?

Comment: I am not able to send test newsletter.....but drupal is able to sent mail when I subscribe the newsletter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your site email address.  I think it's required for outgoing email.  Maybe it's your mail agent.  Any errors on your admin page?

Comment: When I subscribe a mail id for newsletter then mail goes ..... I am not understanding Why is show Sent 0/0 as in image http://i.imgur.com/Blczf.png

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had some problems when sending e-mails with simplenews newsletter module for Drupal. While this is a very good module, sometimes made Drupal cron to fail and stuck. I also wanted full control on sending mails and to avoid some of the limitations of Drupal cron timings. Since I didn't have the time to enhance the simplenews module I did this script to be sure that my mails are sent. This script needs simplenews newsletter module and Drupal in order to work. It has been tested with Drupal 7 (but should work on any version) and simplenews 7.

The script works out of drupal and speaks to the database so its better for performance and mail control. You can set the time step and the mails it sends every time based on your server sending limits. At the end logs any bad mails. For me it is the solution for sending my newsltters.

You can learn more and get the script from

http://tecorange.com/content/mail-send-addon-drupal-simplenews-newsletter